# How To Check for an Index in Oracle

Tags: oracle, metadata

I am writing a schema upgrade script for a product that depends on an Oracle database.  In one area, I need to create an index on a table - if that index does not already exist.  Is there an easy way to check for the existence of an index that I know the name of in an Oracle script?

It would be similar to this in SQL Server:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSINDEXES WHERE NAME = 'myIndex')
  // Then create my myIndex

Answer (score 40, accepted):

select count(*) from user_indexes where index_name = 'myIndex'

sqlplus won't support IF..., though, so you'll have to use anonymous PL/SQL blocks, which means EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to do DDL.

```
DECLARE
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM user_indexes WHERE index_name = 'MYINDEX';
    IF i = 0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX myIndex ...';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Edit: as pointed out, Oracle stores unquoted object names in all uppercase.

Comment: Unless you quote them, database objects (including indexes) are stored in upperdcase. So if you do a CREATE INDEX myIndex, then in USER_INDEXES it will be stored as MYINDEX. And Oracle (by default) won't do case insensitive matches.

Comment: just in addition to this answer: if you need to check if an index exists in another schema, query ALL_INDEXES instead of using USER_INDEXES. Checking USER_INDEXES does not work with an "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = XYZ", you would still query the indexes for the currently logged in user.