# Check if column is indexed

Tags: sql, ssms, varchar, ssms-2012

Is there a way in SSMS to check if a column is indexed?

The reason I ask is because I am thinking of changing a `varchar(500)` to `varchar(MAX)` and have read that if the column is indexed then you cannot insert data greater than `900b`. I want to make sure that this won't be a problem.

Comment: Maybe, you can check this another quetions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138911/how-to-query-the-metadata-of-indexes-in-postgresql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640390/how-to-check-for-an-index-in-oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
USE database;
EXEC sp_helpindex 'yourTable';
```

Comment: It says: `Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.`