# SAS Enterprise Guide: How to get Oracle table indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide (EG) 6.1 and want to know what are the indexes of our Oracle tables. Is there a way to write a program to get this information?

I tried to do:

```
LIBNAME DW ORACLE USER='username' PASSWORD='password' PATH='path.world' SCHEMA='schema';

DATA _NULL_ ;
dsid = OPEN(DW.some_table) ;
isIndexed = ATTRN(dsid,"ISINDEX") ;
PUT isIndexed = ;
RUN ;
```

some_table is the name of (my table), but I get an error:

```
ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the COMPILATION phase.
ERROR 557-185: Variable some_table is not an object.
```

Reference: https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/check-if-index-exists/td-p/1966

Comment: You need to ask Oracle about what indexes are defined, not SAS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640390/how-to-check-for-an-index-in-oracle

Comment: I expect this information in the ´sashelp.vindex´ view or related views.
_If not_, try to access the system views of Oracle. You will probably need more access rights to Oracle to do that.

Comment: @Dirk Horsten I don't think I have enough access right in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

`OPEN` takes a string or a value that resolves to a string.  So you need

```
dsid= OPEN('dw.some_dataset');
```

I don't know if you can use that with Oracle or not, and I don't know whether ATTRN will be useful for this particular purpose or not.  These all work well with SAS datasets, but it's up to the libname engine (and whatever middleware it uses) to implement the functionality that ATTRN would use.

For example, I don't use Oracle but I do have SQL Server tables with indexes, and I can run the above code on them; the code appears to work (it doesn't show errors) but it shows the tables as being unindexed, when they clearly are.

Your *best* bet is to connect using pass-through (`CONNECT TO ...`) instead of libname, and then you can run native Oracle syntax rather than using SAS.